# "Invalid parameter" error when trying to sign request on Digifinex API using Python, despite correct app key and secret. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: python, api, websocket, digital-signature, cryptocurrency

I am trying to create a signature for my websocket requests on the Digifinex crypto API, but I keep getting this error message:

`{'error': {'code': 1, 'message': 'Invalid parameter'}, 'id': 12321}`

My full code looks like this:

```
import websocket
import json
import zlib
import base64
import time
import hmac
import hashlib


appKey = "*key*"
appSecret = "*secret*"


class ToBC:
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.ws = ws
        self.ws = websocket.create_connection("wss://openapi.digifinex.com/ws/v1/")
        self.ws.on_message = self.on_message
        self.ws.on_error = self.on_error
        self.ws.on_close = self.on_close
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        print("init Working")

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print(message)
        ticker = json.loads(message)
        print("Ticker Update:")
        print(f"Symbol: {ticker['symbol']}")
        print(f"Last Price: {ticker['last']}")
        print(f"Volume: {ticker['vol']}")
        print("on_message Working")

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        # called when an error occurs
        print("on_error Working")
        print(error)

    def on_close(self, ws):
        # called when the connection is closed
        print("on_closed Working")
        print("Connection closed")

    def on_open(self, ws):
        # called when the connection is opened
        print("Connection opened")

        # send a ping message
        ws.send('{"id": 12312, "method": "server.ping", "params": []}')
        print(ws.recv())

        # subscribe to a channel
        subscribe_msg = {"id": 12312, "method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": ["trades.BTC_USDT"]}
        ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_msg))
        print(ws.recv())

        while True:
            message = ws.recv()
            print(message)


def sign_request(ts, app_secret):
    # Convert the secret key to bytes
    secret_bytes = bytes(app_secret, 'utf-8')
    # Convert the timestamp to bytes
    timestamp_bytes = str(ts).encode('utf-8')
    # Compute the HMAC SHA256 hash
    hash_digest = hmac.new(secret_bytes, timestamp_bytes, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(hash_digest).decode('utf-8')
    return signature_b64


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wstest = websocket.create_connection("wss://openapi.digifinex.com/ws/v1/")
    tobc = ToBC(wstest)
    timestamp = int(time.time()) * 1000
    base64_encoded = sign_request(timestamp, appSecret)
    print('{"id":12321, "method":"server.auth", "params":[%s, %s, "%s"]}' % (appKey, timestamp, base64_encoded))
    wstest.send('{"id":12321, "method":"server.auth", "params":[%s, %s, "%s"]}' % (appKey, timestamp, base64_encoded))
    msg = zlib.decompress(wstest.recv()).decode('utf-8')
    msg = json.loads(msg)
    print(msg)
```

at the moment I am just running some tests in the if *name*, and I haven't started using the ToBC class yet. The main part to look at is the bottom two code blocks.

I have triple-checked both my key and secret, and they are correct.

The full log I get when I run this code is:

```
init Working
{"id":12321, "method":"server.auth", "params":[*key*, 1679532850000, "ARJFq2wYYO4iDK2ohej24ppeRqtmDASNvxfqugx8wY4="]}
{'error': {'code': 1, 'message': 'Invalid parameter'}, 'id': 12321}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In the Digifinex API docs the only help I get is:

sign: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.Stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(timestamp, secret))

which doesn't do much for me since CryptoJS isn't Python...

Comment: Probably not related, but why are you calling `websocket.create_connection` in the main block, and also in the class `__init__()`?

Comment: At first, when I was coding this, I wasn't sure if it called the ```websocket.create_connection``` properly in the ToBC Class, and I was messing around with wait loops to see if I had to wait for the response. Later, I added it into the main block just for testing purposes. Later when I have confirmed the sign works, I will remove the wstest and run everything in the ToBC class. At the moment all of this is just to see what I can do and how it works.